# select value AND not select value from one column, and merge results

Tags: sql

Ok the title is quite confusing so let me explain with an example.

My table :

```
id  ref  valid
---------------
1   PRO  true
1   OTH  true
2   PRO  true
2   OTH  false
3   PRO  true
4   OTH  true
```

The primary key here is the combination of id and ref.

I want to select all ids having both a valid "PRO" ref AND another valid ref meaning in this case it would return me only "1".
I don't understand how I can do this, IN and SELF JOIN don't seem to be suited for this.

Comment: PRO has to be valid? or it can be false?

Comment: Yes, PRO has to be valid too (question edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id
FROM Table1 a
WHERE ref = 'PRO'
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1 b
    WHERE b.id = a.id
    AND b.ref <> 'PRO'
    AND b.valid = 'true'
)
```

Comment: Awesome ! Why do you have to join on "id" though ?

Comment: Because otherwise the EXISTS query will return true if there is a valid row for ANY id, not just the one concerned

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` :

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM Table1 t1 join Table1 t2 on 
t1.id = t2.id and t1.ref = 'PRO' and t2.ref <> 'PRO'
              and t1.valid= 'true' and t2.valid= 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id
FROM Table1 a
inner join (select id,count(*) count from table1 group by id) as temp
on temp.id=a.id and count>1
where a.ref='PRO'

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
SELECT   id
FROM     val
WHERE    valid='true'
GROUP BY id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT ref)>1
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ref='PRO' THEN ref END)>0
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7ce2/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using inner self join, nested queries and a bit of grouping:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM test
    WHERE (ref = 'PRO') AND (valid = 'true')
) AS A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM test
    WHERE valid = 'true'
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING (
    count( DISTINCT ref ) >1
    )
) AS B
ON A.id = B.id
```

The A subquery queries the table the id with the 'PRO' ref, the B groups and queries the table for the id who have at least two ref with valid to true.